# PDF file page numbering consist with PDF document

Tags: pdf

I'm looking at a PDF file I have. (A textbook from my prof. in PDF version).

When I'm on page "vii" in the textbook, then every PDF Viewer software will tell me that I'm on page 7.

Is it possible to use Adobe Acrobat DC such that these two things a consistent with each other?
If Adobe Acrobat DC can't be used then what can I else do ?
I have PDF Inspector by PSPDFKIT. But I do not know any PDF syntax, so I would need some help with that.

Comment: Does Adobe recognize Roman Numerals? I thought not.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the PDF including "real" page numbers. E.g. evince here on Fedora Linux shows both the "paper" page number and the "printed" page number for files I've written myself in LaTeX.